# Updated Version not available in PLAYSTORE but shows the previous version still

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

**`App OldVersionNo: 1.8.2`**

**`App NewVersionNo: 1.8.3`** (Updated)

My new version **(1.8.3)** of my app was uploaded on **JUN 3 2016** & got published on **JUN 4 2016**. In the below pic we can see the published app `version number`, `date` & `status` of the app.

[image]

Now the Problem is I can't find the **updated app** in playstore, its been more than two day, still I see my **old version** app which is **1.8.2**. In below image we can see the current app version.

[image]

In Google Play Developer Console when I checked the app apk details In that right corner its written `PUBLISHING UPDATE` which was showing more than two days and the status of the **updated app** (1.8.3) is `in production` and **old one** (1.8.2) is `unpublished` all the details what i'm talking about we can see in below image.

[image]

I mailed Playstore Team through help option in Google Play Developer Console, It seems they will response with in 48 hrs, waiting for their response. Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Maybe you should just wait and let the changes propagate to all stores. By stores I mean country specific stores.

Comment: @EvilTak  Yeah waiting for some good to happen .. With lot number of version updates this is the first time  i'm facing issue like this i dont have hope they reply back or the updated app get to the store. After 48 hrs I'm planning for update the version number of the apk & upload it again,  dono it will work or not.

Comment: Yes, waiting is the only solution.  In some recent cases it took about 2 days to propagate properly.

Comment: the same issue occurs waiting for last 2 days.